# Using a Pre-trained Keras model in a Tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a pre-trained Keras model that takes inputs of an arbitrary dimension and outputs a single classification result. I do not need to train the model any further so I would be happy to convert all its trainable variables to constants. I do however need to use the model inside a Tensorflow graph, in the training of another model.

Essentially I want the pre-trained Keras model to act as an input-output operation without any gradients being applied. I have the pre-saved Keras model weights in a h5 file and can load these without a problem, and then use them to initialise the layers in the model.

What I am currently doing is the following:

```
class myKerasModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, shape, trainable=True):
        self.layers = [
               Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', trainable=trainable)
            ]
        inputs = Input(shape)
        Model.__init__(self, inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    def apply_model_to_tensor(self, tensor):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=tensor))
        for layer in self.layers:
            model.add(layer)
        model.trainable = False
        return model
```

After training the model and saving the weights in `weights.h5`, I load the model weights and then try to apply the model with the loaded weights to a Tensor in a Tensorflow session:

```
test_input_tensor = ... # Some Tensorflow tensor of a specified shape (a variable)
mod = myKerasModel(shape, trainable=False)
mod.load_weights('weights.h5')
model = mod.apply_model_to_tensor(test_input_tensor)
# Now use model.output
```

The problem is, I do not think that the weights of `model` are the same as those of `mod`, even though the layers were instance variables and so they are essentially the same object. I am confused about this. Also, the `model` when inspected in Tensorboard is attached to `gradient`, even though I have set trainable to False. I think that this might just be because of the way Keras creates models though, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there a way to load the `model` into a Tensorflow graph with the correct weights and connect it to an arbitrary input tensor?

Comment: Could you show the full code ? Something about layer flags vs models here - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4674

Comment: The full code is quite a bit longer than this so its a bit difficult to show it all and I've just included the relevant bits cut down as proof of concept, but if there's anything you're unsure about please let me know so I can add it to the code.